# PAC script for proxying traffic, iOS

Tags: ios, proxy, pac

I am try create proxying web site through WKWebKit, I am find answer that it is possible only use PAC script (https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/660636).

Tell me please, if I am create this PAC Script, it will be work if user will be use Mobile Network Connection (such as Vodafone .....), or it is will be work only for Wi-Fi connections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's controversial issue, but probably not possible, check this thread - https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/661054